# Python script not work in crontab

Tags: python, cron

Here is my script(randombg.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import random
import subprocess
import os 


BACKGROUND = '/home/david/wallpaper/dell2312'
IGNORE_FILES = ['/home/david/wallpaper/dell2312/.directory']


def enumerate():
    global BACKGROUND
    file_collections = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(BACKGROUND):
        for file in files:
            file_collections.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    return file_collections


def randombg():
    select_files = list(set(enumerate())-set(IGNORE_FILES))
    subprocess.call(['feh', '--bg-scale', random.choice(select_files)])


def main():
    while 1:
        randombg()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have run `chmod a+x randombg.py` and it worked with `python randombg.py` .Let's say its path is `/path/to/randombg.py.` Also, run `/path/to/randombg.py` worked.

However, when I added it to crontab as below:

```
1 * * * * /path/to/randombg.py
```

or

```
01 * * * * python /path/to/randombg.py
```

or

```
01 * * * * /usr/bin/python /path/to/randombg.py
```

All failed.

I can't figure out. Could anyone explain?

PS: ArchLinux

---

More infomation

When I run `ps aux|grep python`, I can't find  the `randombg.py` while sometimes it appears.

---

Addtional  logs from crontab redirect stderr:

```
import: unable to open X server `' @   error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/361.
import: unable to open X server `' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/361.
import: unable to open X server `' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/361.
/home/david/dotfiles/randombg.py: line 9: BACKGROUND: command not found
/home/david/dotfiles/randombg.py: line 10: IGNORE_FILES: command not found
/home/david/dotfiles/randombg.py: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/home/david/dotfiles/randombg.py: line 13: `    def enumerate():'
```

Comment: Your `while` loop will run forever

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove that .

Comment: Can you redirect the errors to a file?

Comment: I tried before like `/path/to/randombg.py > /home/user/randombg.log`, but that log file is empty.

Comment: You have to redirect stderr as well.

Comment: Try this: /path/to/python /path/to/myscript myparam >> /path/to/logfile 2>&1

Comment: BTW, as you're using hasbang, you don't need to call python with script parameter in your cronjob, first example `1 * * * * /path/to/randombg.py ` should be fine. I hope you know what `1 * * * *` means, it runs your command every hour at 1 minute: 08:01, 09:01, 10:01...

Comment: It seems I have misunderstood `1 * * * * ` to `every minute` : 08:01, 08:02, 08:03,... Actually, I would it to run every minute of an hour.

Comment: change it to `* * * * *` then

Comment: @KennyPowers why need `myparam`

Comment: you don't need it, it's just an example. This is in case if you want to give any parameters to python's script. Ignore this one

Comment: It seems that script run from cronjob can't find `$DISPLAY` variable. Try to set it in the subprocess.call.

Comment: @AndreySobolev Yes! I have just captured the error log

Comment: Andrey is right, you need to define it in the subprocess.call or you can import environment variables in your crontab.

Comment: I think you can see the crontab log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your `subprocess.call` to

```
subprocess.call("export DISPLAY=:0; feh --bg-scale " + random.choice(select_files), shell=True)
```

This should export the `DISPLAY` variable, as scripts run from crontab do not have access to environmental variables by default.